# How to implement code before super without creating another method?

Tags: java, list, collections, polymorphism, abstract-class

So I want to implement a code that would scramble the words!!

> It is a homework assignment question.

**Although we are not given the liberty of creating another Method in the class, nor are we allowed to create another field in the class. Everything that we want has to be enclosed within the Constructor parameters.**

and then send the word as an argument for super(arg);

Although would it not be illegal and an error if I put any code before super???

> Note: I also cannot create any variables outside the constructor.
>
> Note2: ScrambledWordPuzzle is a contructor for class ScrambledWordPuzzle that extends another abstract class

**Edit 2: Extra Info**

**Class to make changes:**

```
    public class ScrambledWordPuzzle extends AbstractWordPuzzle {

/**
 * The solution to the puzzle
 */
private String solution;

/**
 * Creates a scrambled word puzzle given the solution word.
 * 
 * @param solutionWord
 *            the puzzle word
 */
public ScrambledWordPuzzle(String solutionWord) {
    // COMPLETE THIS
    // Hint: You need to scramble the letters of the solution word
    // to generate the puzzle word and then set the puzzle word.
    // The easiest way to scramble the letters is to put them
    // into a list, use Collections.shuffle, and then convert the
    // the shuffled list of letters back into a string.
    
    super();        
    this.solution = solutionWord;
    
}

/**
 * Get the solution for this reverse word puzzle.
 * 
 * @return the solution for this reverse word puzzle
 */
@Override
public String getSolution() {
    // COMPLETE THIS
    return this.solution;
}

   }
```

**Abstract Class:**

```
public abstract class AbstractWordPuzzle {
/**
 * The puzzle word.
 */
private String puzzle;

/**
 * Initializes this puzzle to the empty string.
 */
public AbstractWordPuzzle() {
    // COMPLETE THIS
    this.puzzle="";
    
}

/**
 * Initializes this puzzle to the specified puzzle word.
 * 
 * @param puzzleWord
 *            the puzzle word
 */
public AbstractWordPuzzle(String puzzleWord) {
    // COMPLETE THIS
    this.puzzle=puzzleWord;
}

/**
 * Get the solution word. For word puzzles with more than one solution this
 * method returns the solution that comes first in dictionary order.
 * 
 * @return the solution word that comes first in dictionary order
 */
public abstract String getSolution();

/**
 * Get the puzzle word
 * 
 * @return the puzzle word
 */
public final String getPuzzleWord() {
    // ALREADY IMPLEMENTED; DO NOT MODIFY
    return this.puzzle;
}

/**
 * Set the puzzle word for this puzzle.
 * 
 * @param puzzleWord
 *            the puzzle word
 */
public final void setPuzzleWord(String puzzleWord) {
    // COMPLETE THIS
    this.puzzle=puzzleWord;
}
}
```

I need the code before super() because, if it is after the super code, I will not be able to call the variable or whatever it would be in the super(arg).

Comment: Create a static method and call it inline.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, we have an restriction of not creating any method at all!

Comment: Do lambdas count as methods?

Comment: If you cannot use another method or a lamba, you will need to scramble the word prior to calling your `ScrambledWordPuzzle` constructor and pass the scrambled String there.

Comment: We haven't really learned lambdas yet, and I thought of doing it but it kinda does classify as a method so I ignored.

Comment: @Zephyr I know I'd have to pass the string, but how do I send it without making a method.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to provide a meaningful answer. What fields are already defined in class `ScrambledWordPuzzle`? What constructors are available in the superclass? What do the instructions mean by "set the puzzle word"? Why do you feel you need to do something before calling `super()`; why not after?

Comment: I assume, the question migh be abit more understandable now??

Comment: Much less so. The code is right there. What are you asking?

Comment: what do you mean the code is right there??

Comment: You asked how to run code before a super() call. The answer is: within the parameter call, like super(the code here runs before the super call).

Comment: Although how would I use Colections and create a List and then sending the String version of list all inside of the super();

Comment: I know right?!?? Our prof is like go extra!, you are university students, not high school! -_-

Answer (score -2):

Ok, so no methods allowed. Then everything should be inline.

```
public ScrambledWordPuzzle(String solutionWord) {
    super(new MyCollection(solutionWord.split("")).shuffle().toString());
}
```

Comment: Where does `MyCollection` come from?

Comment: where is MyCollection coming from?

Comment: Well, that's the assignment work. The original question wants to know how to run code before a super() call, and the answer is "inline, within the parameter call"